# Create report in Monthly calendar format to display data in each column of date

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a report in which I will display number of registered users on my website on daily basis in each month.

I am using ASP.NET 4.5 and **C#** for back-end coding. I am fetching data from Database to count the daily registered users using **SQL Server 2008**.

This is my stored procedure where I am retrieving data from table on daily basis registered users.

```
select  tb.Month, 
        tb.day, 
        COUNT(tb.Month) as Total 
from (
    select  intId, 
            MONTH(dtRegDate) as Months, 
            datename(month, dtRegDate) as Month, 
            DATENAME(DAY, dtRegDate) as day
    from tblUserDetails
    ) tb
group by tb.Month, tb.day, Months
order by tb.Months
```

[image: Result of Stored Procedure]

Now I want to display this Result data in table format like picture given below.

Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to count `intID` and not the `Month`. You can use pivoting:

```
;WITH cte AS (
select  tb.[Months],
        tb.[Month], 
        tb.[Day], 
        COUNT(tb.intId) as [Total]
from (
        select  intId, 
                MONTH(dtRegDate) as [Months],
                datename(month, dtRegDate) as [Month], 
                DATENAME(DAY, dtRegDate) as [Day]
        from tblUserDetails
    ) tb
group by tb.Month, tb.day, Months
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
PIVOT (
    SUM([Total]) FOR [Day] IN ([1],[2],[3]...)
) pvt
order by [Months]
```

Comment: OMG :D @gofr1 , I can't even think at this level. This answer is just amazing. THANKS A LOT, YOU SAVED MY TONS OF MINUTES :)

Comment: can you explain (teach) me, how this PIVOTING works? I tried to understand yesterday but I wasn't able to understand it. Thanks again.

Comment: I want to display 0 instead of `NULL` in above query, can you please tell where to apply `ISNULL` function?

Comment: At first we get a table like on your screenshot than we use any aggregate function (max, min, sum, avg) and apply it on column we'd like to count (`Total`) and than we determine the column, from which row values will be shown as columns (`Days`). More info [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-Sql-Query)

Comment: You are getting `NULL`s because you have no data for some month/days (f.e. 7,15,21 of August from your screenshot). There is two ways to get rid of nulls: first is to use `[Month],ISNULL([1],0) as [1],...,ISNULL([n],0) as [n]
` instead of `*` in last select from CTE, second is to use some calendar table UNION it with your table that will fill in the gaps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are genius :)